# Adapt Alamofire requests in RetryPolice

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofire5

i used `RetryPolicy` in my code with this class:

```swift
open class ConnectionLostRetryPolicy: RetryPolicy {
    public init(retryLimit: UInt = RetryPolicy.defaultRetryLimit,
                exponentialBackoffBase: UInt = RetryPolicy.defaultExponentialBackoffBase,
                exponentialBackoffScale: Double = RetryPolicy.defaultExponentialBackoffScale,
                retryableHTTPMethods: Set<HTTPMethod> = RetryPolicy.defaultRetryableHTTPMethods) {
        super.init(retryLimit: retryLimit,
                   exponentialBackoffBase: exponentialBackoffBase,
                   exponentialBackoffScale: exponentialBackoffScale,
                   retryableHTTPMethods: retryableHTTPMethods,
                   retryableHTTPStatusCodes: [],
                   retryableURLErrorCodes: [.networkConnectionLost])
    }

    public func adapt(_ urlRequest: URLRequest, for session: Session, completion: @escaping (Result<URLRequest, Error>) -> Void) {
        print("TEST")
    }
}
```

and i want to adapt per request to change timeout time. but `adapt` func does not called. what should i do?

i used it like this:

```swift
let alamofire = AlamofireSession.shared
alamofire.session = Session(interceptor: ConnectionLostRetryPolicy())
```

Comment: Try to replace `Result<URLRequest, Error>` with `Swift.Result<URLRequest, Error>`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58852844/alamofire-5-0-0-rc-3-requestinterceptor-adapt-method-not-being-called-of-alamofi ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like some sort of wrapper for Alamofire, as `AlamofireSession` isn't something Alamofire provides. An Alamofire `Session` has an underlying `.session`, which is the `URLSession`. I suggest you look into whatever wrapper you're using.

Comment: can you give an example how to use ‘RetryPolicy’ with Alamofire?

Comment: Read our documentation, there are many examples.